# No se pasa el valor del input al switch PHP

Tags: php, html

Cuando se escoge la  opcion 1, te lleva al case de la suma de dos numeros, pero cuando agrego los dos numeros en los input y le doy clic en sumar no muestra el resultado, no muestra nada.

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Switch </h1>
<form name="formularioDatos" method="GET">

Escoga una opcion: <input type="text" name="opcion">
<br/><br/>  
<input type="submit" name="enter" value="Enter">
</form>



<?php 
$opcion = $_GET['opcion'] ?? '';?>

    <?php  switch ($opcion) {
        case "1":
            echo "Suma";?>
            <form   method="GET">
                <br/><br/> 
                Escribe el numero 1: <input type="number" name="numero1">
                <br/><br/>
                Escribe el numero 2: <input type="number" name="numero2">
                <br/><br/>  
                <input type="submit" name="suma" value="suma">
            <br/>           
            </form>
            <?php 

             if(isset($_GET['suma'])) {
                Sumar();
                }

            function Sumar(){
                    $numero1 = $_GET['numero1'];  
                    $numero2 = $_GET['numero2'];  
                    $sum =  $numero1+$numero2;     
                    echo "La suma es ".$sum;  
                }
            break;
            case "2":
            echo "Resta";
            break;

        }?>

</body>
</html>
```

Cuando se escoge la  opcion 1, te lleva al case de la suma de dos numeros, pero cuando agrego los dos numeros en los input y le doy clic en sumar no muestra el resultado, no muestra nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando envias el segundo formulario pierdes el valor que da entrada al switch, por lo tanto deberas enviar tambien este valor con input hidden

```
Escribe el numero 2: <input type="number" name="numero2">
                <br/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="opcion" value="1"/>
<input type="submit" name="suma" value="suma">
```

Comment: Gracias! si sirvio!